# Weird question? Smallest positive whole number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a math question I can't figure out...

Suppose you move the last digit of a positive whole number to the front of the number. (i.e 142 becomes 214 and 1234 becomes 4123)

Find the smallest positive whole number where performing this process exactly doubles the value of the original number.

I have no idea where to start (this problem is just for fun)

What solutions can you all come up with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  Let the original number be $10a+b$, where $b$ is the last digit and $a$ is all the rest.  Then we have $2(10a+b)=a+b10^n$ where $n$ is the number of digits in $a$. This gives $19a=b(10^n-2)$ so you need to find an $n$ such that $19$ divides into $10^n-2$

Comment: And since $10\cdot 2\equiv 1\pmod {19}$, we know it has a solution.

Comment: I can't find the number... How'd you get it?

Comment: @Michael Can you find $n$?

Comment: So we need to find $k$, such that $19k = 99...998$ so $k =\lfloor \frac{1}{19} 10^n \rfloor $ with $n$ big enough such that the last digit is 2 ... This works, but looks kinda hacky, is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: @DenDenDo: We need $10^n \equiv 2 \pmod {19}$, so we can just search (no more than $18$ such powers, reducing $\pmod {19}$ each time to keep the numbers from overflowing), and see if we find $2$.  If we find one, we know the smallest $n$  If we don't find one (we will), we can report that there is no solution.  Now since $1 \le b \le 9$ we can try all the $b$'s to see if $a$ comes out with the right number of digits.

Comment: @RossMillikan Actually, from Thomas Andrews's comment it appears that $10^{17}\equiv 2\pmod {19}$.  Doesn't mean it's the smallest such value, but it appears $10$ is a primitive root $\pmod{19}$.  I haven't posted more because the OP hasn't provided his thoughts.